# Is there any way to implement parental controls in image searches on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, parental-controls

I'm trying to find a way to enable parental controls on image searches.

My daughter (7) has a surface pro with Windows 10, but the parental controls seem to only apply to actual sites.

If she does a search on google or bing the image results don't seem to be filtered.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Bing and Google both allow you to enable what they call "Safe Search" which filters more mature content.  In both cases though unless your daughter is logged in as your ( Microsoft Account, Google Account ) its trivial to change this setting.

Comment: Since she's 7 I for now control the account that she uses, and on Windows 10 to enable parental controls it's required that we create a new account. But anyway, I assume what you're saying is that the browsers (Chrome, IE) have their own parental settings? There's no way to do it via Windows Family?

Comment: The search engines have it.  Windows Family cannot control he search results of a search engine.  If you want web filtering based on content there are solutions for that beyond what I describe also.  If you meant local image searches you should clarify your question.

Comment: That might be what I'm not understanding. In the Windows Family settings, we have an option to block inappropriate sites and bing search filtering. In the case of Bing this does not seem to work for image searches, but I do understand that it would not work on Chrome. But it should work on Google inside IE. Because in IE how can I configure Google?

Comment: You log into your Google account and enable that feature within your Google Search engine.  If you what image filtering based on content on any search engine that would require a third-party filtering solution.  Content filtering sites is simplistic in nature.  Image filtering its a great deal harder.